# Access Services and SharePoint Apps Config

Tags: 2013, 2016, apps-development, dns, access-services

I have been trying to configure access services and apps configure for SharePoint 2013 and 2016 on premise. Does SharePoint Apps have to be configured for access services to work? How must my DNS have to be setup to for Access Services to work?

This is the articles I have been using :
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2013/07/14/access-services-2013-setup-for-an-on-premises-installation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , in SharePoint 2013 to Access Services work we need to Configure App for SharePoint 2013 as these Access Services uses the new app model in SharePoint 2013.

and to configure the App we need a App domain where all these app will be hosted with the unique app id .

to configure app we need to create two service applications :

1.App Management Service Application
2.Subscription Settings service application

after configuring these service application we need to configure the app url and domain from the App Settings page in Central Administration.

[image]

follow this article [Set up an on-premises development environment for SharePoint Add-ins](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/set-up-an-on-premises-development-environment-for-sharepoint-add-ins) that has clear explainations about all these configurations.